# Save Image to DB via URL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there anyway to save an image to a database in MongoDB via a url without saving the image locally first.  For example there is an image element with 
a url for the src ie.

```
<img src="somesite.com/1.jpg" />
```

Is there a way to save that image directly to the db without downloading the image locally first?  I don't mean simply storing the image address but the image itself.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: check this out [link](https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2408370). Somebody already tried it

Comment: In our solution rather than storing images to MongoDB, we store them to Azure blob storage and store links to mongoDB this way i can consume it directly from blob storage onto my front end without going through my nodejs server for this

Comment: I have tried that but it threw an error when used with a url.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Comment: you will have to store the image either in a temp directory on the server or in memory before you move it to MongoDB. You cant stream it directly from client side to mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

In the end, temporarily storing the file on a node server worked well.